# M thread as leadscrew

Tags: mechanical-engineering, threads

Hello I was searching net but can find information. I am doing a hobbyist project. I would like use shaft with metric triangular thread as a leadscrew. Can I do that? I know ACME will be loads better but they are not easy to get my hands on where I live. 
Also if it helps I am trying to create very miniature milling machine, controled by hand and maybe with a lathe built-in. I would of course not use it for anything too precise. Just for milling out in aluminium and wood for artistic purposes. Or to make precision tabletop drill ( here it shouldn't interfere right ? )

Comment: Once you've made a lathe, you can cut your own ACME screw - fit that, then cut a more accurate one ;)

Comment: Oh thank you so using screw makes more accurate screw? I always wondered how we made stuff work beter when we didn't have a good tools to be so precise yet. 

So I can in fact use M thread without it exploding in my face ?

Comment: A suitably sized M thread will not explode in your face, no. The trouble with V threads is that they have a higher sliding friction (good when you don't want your bolt falling out, bad when you're trying to move a lathe slide). For a small lathe, it's not a problem. The Wikipedia article on leadscrews explains this, and actually says "Nevertheless, V-threads are sometimes successfully used as leadscrews, for example on microlathes and micromills." This sounds exactly like your application.

Comment: "*I always wondered how we made stuff work beter when we didn't have a good tools to be so precise yet.*" Yes, we would never have progressed beyond stone hammers if we couldn't make better tools with the ones we've got.

Comment: I know it's dumb but I always assumed they just made that by making multiple copies and using best one. I never thought you can make something more precise with something less precise. Nevertheless thank you all for replies. I want to make it from scratch so as hobbyist I never would afford putting some fancy screw even before I found out if I want to invest more into a project. Also I am in general not that experienced in lathes so i guess I don't know if it's a flight of fancy or genuine interest yet.